# Heigth's diferentes para cada Grid - React-JS + Material UI

Tags: react, material-ui

Quero que as Grids não fiquem alinhadas, tentei ver na documentação porém não encontrei nada relacionado, segue abaixo o código atual que estou usando

```
<Grid container spacing={0.5}  >
    <Grid item xs={6} >
        <Paper elevation={5} >
            <Anual pedidos={props.pedidos} />
        </Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} >
        <Paper elevation={5} style={{ height: "500px" }}>

        </Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Paper elevation={5} style={{ height: "300px" }}>

        </Paper>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[Código ATUAL (Imagem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1f6.jpg)

[Objetivo (Imagem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sD6s.jpg)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A solução que achei foi essa!
como ninguém soube ajudar, tive que me virar.

```html
<Grid container spacing={0.1}  >
    <Grid item md={12} lg={6} justifyContent="center">
        <Paper elevation={5} style={{ margin: 5, marginBottom: 10 }} square>
      
        </Paper>
        <Paper elevation={5} style={{ margin: 5 }} square>

        </Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item md={12} lg={6} >
        <Paper elevation={5} style={{ margin: 5, height: "710px", textAlign: "center" }} square>

        </Paper>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).